# Any way to determine a user's video length limit?

Tags: youtube-api

Is there any way to determine the duration/length limit for a user when using Youtube API 3.0 to upload a video?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate them to "Video Manager>Channel Settings>Features" and click on the "Enable" button in front of "Unlimited Uploads".  (There may be an easier way to do this with the API)

Clearly, after performing this process, you can conclude that there is no limit, and do whatever it is you wanted to do that would require uploading longer videos.